# Image width exceeds container width when using CSS grid feature

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm currently working on some layout and I have an issue with image width exceeding the container width when applying CSS grid rules.

Please, take a look at the code below.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(300px, 400px);
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-column: 3;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/900x400" alt="" width="900" height="400">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering what might cause that issue. The sidebar has to be between 300px and 400px. The content container should take the rest.
For some reason, the image is breaking this layout setup.

https://codepen.io/sunpietro/pen/ZyNgqe

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? If I misunderstood your question just let me know.

Comment: @Michael_B yes, I'm still looking for an answer. In the meantime I fixed it by setting a fixed width to a content container. For some reason, when there's auto value in grid-template-columns, the content container tries to be the same width as its content (which is bigger then the container meant to be)

Comment: Have you tried `1fr` instead of `auto`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed `grid-template-columns`. It should `be grid-template-columns: auto 1fr minmax(300px, 400px)`. `auto` for image, `1fr` for `content`, and `minmax(300px, 400px) for`sidebar` (it resides in 3rd column). Demo:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr minmax(300px, 400px);
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-column: 3;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/900x400" alt="" width="900" height="400">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a two-column grid.

```
grid-template-columns: auto minmax(300px, 400px);
```

This means there are three grid column lines: 1, 2 and 3.

The image is nested in a grid item which occupies the first column:

```
.content {
   grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
```

But you have the sidebar skipping the second column and starting at grid column line 3 (the end of the explicit grid):

```
.sidebar {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

This breaks down to:

```
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-column-end: auto;
```

So there's nothing in the second column.

Try this instead:

```
.sidebar {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJQPxQ)